# Why Meteor.publish is not a function error showing for the code in the server folder?

Tags: meteor

In the meteor project, I have a server folder in which there is a file publish.js. Source of code of publish.js:

```
  if (Meteor.isServer){
       Meteor.publish('NotesList', function(){
                return NotesList.find();
        });
   }
```

Meteor.isServer check is not required as the code is already in the server folder, but when the website runs on Heroku server, I get error if I don't put Meteor.isServer check [image]

I don't have to put the Meteor.isServer check when the app is running on localhost as no error showing locally. But in the code deployed on heroku, I have to put Meteor.isServer check. I am using Meteor1.4 version. I am not able to figure out the reason behind this error on server. Does anyone know why this error is showing only on server?

Comment: import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'; have you imported this ?? are these two things done ..   'meteor remove insecure' and 'meteor remove autopublish'  ?

Comment: insecure and auto publish packages are already removed. What is the purpose of import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor? How is it related to the issues I have mentioned?

Comment: both in react with meteor and angular 2 with meteor we have to import Meteor to use its functionality. this error may be coming because of missing Meteor